# How to search a string in the searched substring in mongodb and mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex, database, mongodb, sql-like

"user" collection/table data in my database looks like this:-

```
{
 _id: 1,
 name: "Vikas",
 subject: "Computers"
},
{
 _id: 2,
 name: "Hello",
 subject: "Computers"
},
{
 _id: 3,
 name: "Abc",
 subject: "Mechanical"
}
```

The below queries will give the result of mechanical data:-

Mongodb:-

`db.test.find({subject: /mech/i})` ->

Mysql:-

```
select * from test where subject like "%mech%"
```

But I want the search like, if I search "mechanicalData", then this will not give the result of mechanical data.

I hope I am able to clear my question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want search ex. "PersonalComputers" and find "Computers"?

Comment: Nope. If I search PersonalComputerTech, then it should fetch all the relevant data which consists of PersonalComputers

Answer (score 0):

```
For MongoDB    
db.test.find({subject: /^mech$/i}) //Search exact word
db.test.find({subject: /mech$/i}) //Search word which ending with "mech"
db.test.find({subject: /^mech/i}) //Search word which start with "mech"
db.test.find({subject: /mech/i}) //Search word at any position


For Mysql
select * from test where subject like "mech" //Search exact word
select * from test where subject like "%mech" //Search word which ending with "metch"
select * from test where subject like "mech%" //Search word which start with "metch"
select * from test where subject like "%mech%" //Search word at any position
```

Comment: db.test.find({subject: /mech/i}) //Search word at any position (This query I already mention but you are provide same

Comment: I know that you are already mentioned but I write all possible way for mysql and mongodb.

Comment: So its not the answer

Answer (score 0):

(Related to MySQL.)

There is no search mechanism that understands languages enough to realize that "mechanical data" and "mechanicaldata" are the same.

You can, on an individual basis, do that, but not in a general case.

```
REGEXP "mechanical ?data"
```

The `?` means "optional space".

```
LIKE "%mechanical%data"
```

would also find both "mechanicalData" and "mechanical data".  However, it would also find "mechanical foobar data"

Comment: I didn't said "mechanical data" and "mechanicaldata" are the same.